# Javascript to Java: anonymous functions and dynamic objects

Tags: javascript, java, types

What would be the **shortest** way to do something like this in Java

```
var coolthing = {
  start : function() { start(); },
  end   : function() { end(); },
  fool  : 'hardy'
}
```

Here we have anonymous functions as values of an 'anonymous' object. Should I use a `Map` ? Can functions be defined as the value type at all ? How would I mix types ? Etcetera.

---

Note for the zealous mods: I am asking for the shortest way. That is not opinion-based.

Comment: You do not have anonymous functions nor do you have an anonymous object. The functions are being stored as key values and the object is being stored as `coolthing`, so there is no anonymous anything here.

Comment: Any java attempts that have issues?

Comment: According to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) anonymous classes require `The name of an interface to implement or a class to extend.` so if you truly need `coolthing` to behave like a class/object, you will need some sort of superclass or interface.

Comment: Trying to directly translate from JavaScript to Java is going to give you a very clumsy solution. Java isn't designed to be a scripting language. You're better off starting over and doing things the Java way: classes and interfaces. I don't recommend using a `Map`, because you will lose type safety if the values need to be different types.

Comment: @csm_dev as for being short and efficient, all my java attempts have issues :-)

Comment: @4castle , I understand .. that is why I put the fool:hardy in the example.

Comment: That's why it is hard. You still thinking in JavaScript way. There is so many things you need to know on Java only within the code snippet: Strongly type, classes, delegate. You can't simply pass function around. Cleanup your mind and start writing Java classes.

Comment: This isn't directly translatable into java because of differences in how the two languages handle the concept of 'this', which is implied in your call to start() and end(). In java 'this' always and only points to the object executing the function that calls start() or end(), so this would become a recursive call. In javascript of course, 'this' can point to almost anything at all, and it is that context in which start() or end() are called. Baring the fact that java is more wordy the basic structure of your code directly and trivially translates into java. This is a basic decorator though...

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. You could create a map, which is similar to an anonymous object, except the values all have to be the same type. Java 9 provides an easy way to construct a map. With Java 8 you can have lambdas which are actually anonymous classes, but look like functions. You have [many functional interfaces to choose from](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html), and you can create your own.

```
Map<String, Supplier<Integer>> coolthing = Map.of("start", () -> {return 1;}, "end", () -> {return 2;});
```

Comment: Nice - how would you handle the `fool` bit which is, presumably, a property of `coolthing` and thus desired to be get/set?

Comment: Can't do that with a map, all the values have to be one type. You can of course create a class or an interface with multiple named fields of different types.